# HTTP over UDP implementation in Java

Tags: netty, apache-camel

Have you had any experience with HTTP over UDP with Netty, or a similar framework? (MINA, CAMEL)?  We get mixed results and are interested in learning about your experience with running formal protocols over UDP.

Edit:  Any C/S protocol that transfers control+data and runs over UDP would be interesting to learn about:  SMTP, HTTP, FTP...  we're interested in hearing about people who successfully implemented / used such protocols with UDP.

Comment: can you share more why you would like to use UDP specifically?

Comment: Sure.  In some cases, for example multi-layered DMZs or firewalls in organizations, we are confined to working via UDP.  Some routing devices we use can only transfer UDP.  But I'd love to be able to use a mature protocol such as HTTP.

Answer (score 3):

**===== UPDATE =====**

I don't know much about it, but SCTP provides some of the same stream control as TCP and can be tunneled over UDP. I mention it because I believe netty 4 has support for SCTP transport, so this might be an option for you.

---

HTTP assumes a reliable transmission protocol, so although you can use it over UDP, you're on your own. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http):

> HTTP is an application layer protocol designed within the framework of
>   the Internet Protocol Suite. Its definition presumes an underlying and
>   reliable transport layer protocol,[2] and Transmission Control
>   Protocol (TCP) predominates for this purpose. However HTTP can use
>   unreliable protocols such as the User Datagram Protocol (UDP), for
>   example in Simple Service Discovery Protocol (SSDP).

Comment: Thanks @Nicholas, I am aware of what HTTP is... hence my question.  Pointing to the mainstream use does not really answer this question.  I'd just like to hear people who use HTTP in the non-conventional way.

Comment: Thanks again @Nicholas, there are many posts on StackOverflow concerning SCTP not being compatible with default configurations of many firewalls, and also not being installed on Windows systems.  It *could* be a viable course of action otherwise, so I appreciate your effort in suggesting it.